# UIPageViewController showing part of next childViewController

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `UIPageViewController` that shows 3 child view controllers. The controller is working fine, but on the first page he shows a few vertical columns of pixels from the second page (you can see the grey of the search bar and a selected cell). This behavior is not occurring between the 2nd and 3rd child VC.

First VC (see the overlap on the right side)
[image]
Second VC (no overlap on the left or right from the 1st or 3rd)
[image]
Third VC: 
[image]

The code relevant to this issue is here: http://pastebin.com/Dn7nkKHj

Could this be an auto-layout issue? Or an issue with the `UIPageViewController`. And how can I avoid/correct it?

Comment: After getting the frame from the `UITableView` in the first VC, it appears the x-pos is -4. I did not define that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug, filed in bug reporter as bug n° 22947439

There is a workaround however:

[image]

In the above screenshot, I have circled with a red dashed line the setting you need to un-check. After this, you need to make sure the “constant” value is not -20, but 0. Repeat this for all the leading and trailing constraints of your table views.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is an auto layout issue because if there is some issue due to auto layout it will create same effect with second and third view controllers also.
 Can you please share our storyboard so that I can look check whether there is some auto layout issue.

Comment: Sure, storyboard is here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/293833/Main.storyboard

Comment: this is in xml format.Kindly attach screenshots showing the constraint also.

Comment: Part 1/2 https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/293833/Schermafbeelding%202015-09-28%20om%2013.14.51.png 
Part 2/2 https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/293833/Schermafbeelding%202015-09-28%20om%2013.15.02.png

Comment: Try to set the frame of your page view controller. This might can help you.

Comment: Setting the frame to the exact same frame of the parent VC did not work.